# Could we have a way to 'close' or otherwise archive outdated post on teams?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, historical-lock, outdated-information, custom-close-reasons

Funnily enough, doing so on main sites is a thing that's being worked on, in a manner of speaking.

I'm considering two specific scenarios

1. There's a specific situation that's no longer relevant at present. There's *some* useful information there but its completely irrelevant to the org other than as an artefact that shows past decisions. We'd like to keep it around as a reference as if there's sufficient turnover, no one would remember why a decision was made. We have a few questions involving a resource that was used temporarily in one of the teams I am in. The context would be useful for talking about historic decisions to new folks, especially since we lost a significant portion of the folks involved in the original decision recently.
2. In many organisations - there may be 'current', legacy or maybe even 'obsolete, but we haven't gotten clearance to decommission' environments. There is no 'new' information to add but it might need to be looked up. While my current workplace doesn't use teams, this is something we grapple with in our documentation.

In theory, we could use tags as one approach, and we are. However tags, or combination of tags are not *that* obvious. That's the approach we have on hand one.

There's three specific tools/approaches that would be useful here

- the ability to add 'custom' close reasons. These would indicate how and why a question was closed, add an obvious post notice, and prevent additional answers. This could be done at a user level, reducing the load on the admins
- an analogue to the 'historical lock' - which would serve many of the same purposes *and* freeze the post in its current state.
- the ability to add post notices, describing the situation.

All three would have additional utility. Custom closures are a swiss army knife tool, locking might be useful if a post needs to be frozen in time and known to be consistent from the time it was locked, and post notices would allow for fixed/obvious bits of context for new users who haven't quite gotten the hang of the organisational lore.

Comment: If someone asks why something was done in certain way, it's still useful. It doesn't need to be "achieved". It already is.

Comment: Teams now has a "Mark obsolete" button for questions, shown to mods/admins (and presumably it can be applied via the Content Health queue as well, for Teams with that feature). Marking a question as obsolete causes the post to be locked with an "Obsolete" post notice. (I don't recall when this feature was added.) Does that fulfill this feature request, as an analogue to the historical lock?

Comment: (As a note, I think the "Obsolete" lock option also appears in the Mod menu on all SE network sites. Not sure if there have been any announcements about whether that's intentional.)

Comment: Now I need to remember what this was about a yearish on. Sounds like it tho